# Web3py. Error getting events using Infura: "The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available"

Tags: web3.py, infura

I'm trying to get all events from contract, but get error:
"ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_newFilter does not exist/is not available'}"

I'm using Web3py and Infura. My code:

```
myfilter = <myContract>.events.<MyEvent>.createFilter(fromBlock=0)
```

or

```
myFilter = web3.eth.filter({"address": <myContractAddress>})
```

Why is this error? How do I get events? 
Help me please.

Comment: How are you connecting to Infura? `eth_newFilter` is only available via websocket.

Comment: Like this:
`from web3 import Web3`    
`PROVIDER = 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxx'`    
`web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(PROVIDER))`

Comment: @iamdefinitelyahuman So I don't know why this error. As you can see in the code, I use Infura.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that Infura only exposes the [`eth_newFilter`](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/wss/eth_newFilter) endpoint via websockets, but you are connecting via https.

Try using a [`WebsocketProvider`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#websocketprovider) when declaring your `web3` instance, as shown in the following example:

```py
from web3 import Web3

PROVIDER = "wss://ropsten.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(PROVIDER))
```

Comment: Will all other methods work correctly? (via WebsocketProvider) And it will not affect  speed of working with Infura?

Comment: Yes, per the [infura docs](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/wss/introduction) all https endpoints will be available.  And websockets is typically quicker.

Comment: Thank you! But I have other error

Comment: "websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: Status code not 101: 404"

Comment: for some reason, after connecting to Ropsten via Infura WebsocketProvider - for any action (for example, getBalance) this error:(

Comment: ahh sorry, i made a mistake in the provider URL! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Now, no errors! Super!:)

Comment: [As of 2020](https://blog.infura.io/filters-support-over-https/), Infura supports `eth_newFilter` over HTTPS. But its support is limited (e.g. you can't create a filter on pending logs and it seems to be available only on some endpoints)